# Why my curl command responds successfully, and wget command return 405 response?

Tags: docker, shell, http, kubernetes, client-server

I am executing two commands as follows:

```
curl http://somehost:port/endpoin
```

this return me successful response.

Whereas if I execute the same command with wget as follows:

```
wget --spider -S http://somehost:port/endpoint
```

this gives me a 405 Method not allowed error.

If I simply do wget `http://somehost:port/endpoint` I can downoad the file successfully.

Can someone help me understand the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this command

```
curl http://somehost:port/endpoin
```

It sends request `GET` method.

But another one use `HEAD` method. So that service may only allows `GET` method and deny others.

Comment: Is there a way where I could specify `not to download a file and don't pass the header as well`?

Answer (score 0):

`--spider` argument specified that the request issued is of type `HEAD` and not `GET` or `POST`

following command works just fine thanks to @xirehat

```
wget -S http://somehost:port/endpoint
```